# TFS build - "content" build type files not present in a unit test's \out folder?

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I have a solution containing a unit test project and various other projects (which the unit tests references). One of these projects references an assembly which in turn depends on a native interop DLL, which I've added to the project with a build action of "Content", and "Copy Always".

I can build and run the unit tests fine on my PC, but they fail during a TFS (2012) build. In can see the interop DLL in the server's `\build\...\bin\` folder, but it's not in the `\build\...\tst\[test_name]\Out\` folder.

I assume TFS is trying to be clever by copying what it *thinks* are the unit test's dependencies? I've tried adding the interop DLL to the unit test project (in the same manner as above), but it makes no difference. I've also tried adding a [DeploymentItem] attribute to one of the unit tests (to copy the interop DLL), but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: As you are using a non default folder structure you will likely have to use a pre-test or post-build PowerShell to re-arrange the bits to your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out, although it wasn't very obvious. By default, a TFS build creates three subfolders:- \bin, \src and \tst. The latter is where the test project and its dependencies get copied (to an \Out subfolder), but my interop DLL won't be copied as it isn't a managed project dependency. *This isn't a problem on my dev PC - when the unit test project is built, Visual Studio honours the interop DLL's "copy always" option (even though it's in a different project), ensuring that it gets copied to the unit test project's \bin folder.*

I tried the `[DeploymentItem]` attribute but didn't have much luck with that - there are some conflicting articles about where the paths are relative to, and it also seems that you have to have a .testsettings file present for this to work. After spending a *long* time checking-in and testing all sorts of permutations, I never had any success with this.

I also tried deploying the files using a .testsettings file ("Deployment" tab). To complicate things, my interop DLL must reside in a subfolder under the \bin folder (it's SQLite.Interop.dll, if anyone is interested). The .testsettings Deployment tab doesn't seem to honour folder structure, so the interop DLL would get copied into the \tst\Out folder, rather than the required subfolder.

In the end, I was able to configure the build to run unit tests from the TFS server's \bin folder, so it works in a comparable way to a dev PC:-

1. Create a .testsettings file and add it to the solution. In the properties dialog, "Deployment" tab, I ticked the "Enable Deployment" checkbox. I *don't* specify any files on this tab.
2. Check the file in to TFS, then edit my build definition and set Process -> Automated Tests -> Test Assembly -> Run Settings File accordingly.